# RegExp replace text in string ignoring HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I am replacing a users search term with a yellow highlight to indicate what they're currently searching for / what is being highlighted in the returned such, however it breaks at the point that it matches a HTML element - which is obviously correct but unintended.

I need the RegExp to look for the search term, but ignore any HTML tags.

`data` is coming from an Ajax call as per below;

```
function data_fetch() {

    $search_term = esc_attr($_POST['keyword'] );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 's' => $search_term ) );

    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        echo '<ul>';
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();

            $title = get_the_title();

            if (stripos($title, $search_term) !== false) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php }

        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();
    else:
        echo 'There are no posts that match your request';

    endif;

    echo '</ul>';

    die();
}
```

```
function fetch() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#search').val() },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            const searchTerm = jQuery('#search').val();
            const regex = new RegExp(searchTerm, "gi");

            const newData = data.replace(regex, function(searchTerm) {
                return '<span>' + searchTerm + '</span>'
            });

            jQuery('#searchdata').html( newData );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: And what is `data`?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question to include that. Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the regular expression to ensure that you are only looking for text that lies between `<a>` and `</a>` tags:

```
const regex = new RegExp('(<a href="[^"]+">)((?:(?!</a>).)*?)(' + searchTerm + ')', "gi");
```

And then:

```
let newData = data.replace(regex, '$1$2<span>$3</span>');
```

As a demo:

```js
let searchTerm = 'li';
const regex = new RegExp('(<a href="[^"]+">)((?:(?!</a>).)*?)(' + searchTerm + ')', "gi");
console.log(regex);
let data = '<li><a href="some href">anybody see a lithesome cat?</a></li>';
let newData = data.replace(regex, '$1$2<span>$3</span>');
console.log(newData);
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nwmdbo/1/)

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. Out of curiousity, I don't suppose you know why someone would downvote my question and propose it be closed for lacking details or clairty? You seemed to get the jist of what I was trying to achieve just fine. StackOverflow is such an odd place.

Comment: Well, to be honest, your question without the information I solicited from you, really could not be answered because it was lacking some important details. While some people would rather give the person a chance to provide the information, others rush to issue a close vote. They are not necessarily wrong, but at least they should provide a comment explaining why since the close vote itself is often not descriptive enough. But in other case people just don't take the rime to try to understand what the OP is getting at. If I don't have the time or patience for such a question, I just move on.

Comment: Have you considered having your PHP routine `data_fetch` do the regex replace operation on the query *prior* to wrapping the data in links and within a list?